# How can I get a dataframe of frequency and time from a wav file in R?

Tags: r, audio, wav

I'd like to try to distinguish two speakers in a wav file. The most straightforward way seems like it should be to extract frequency info from the file, and use time to match frequency with a given part of the file. I don't see a function in tuneR or seewave to easily extract a dataframe like this. What's the easiest way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that might help. The `spectro` function returns time, frequency and amplitude and with some manipulation using functions in `reshape2` and `dplyr` you can get a data frame.

```
library(seewave)
library(tuneR)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

data("pellucens")
writeWave(pellucens, "pellucens.wav")
wav = readWave("pellucens.wav")

ss = spectro(wav, plot = F)
mm =
  melt(ss$amp, value.name = "Amplitude") %>%
  dplyr::select(FrequencyIndex = Var1, TimeIndex = Var2, Amplitude)
ff =
  melt(ss$freq, value.name = "Frequency") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(FrequencyIndex = row_number(), Frequency = Frequency * 1000)
tt =
  melt(ss$time, value.name = "Time") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(TimeIndex = row_number())
sp =
  mm %>%
  dplyr::left_join(ff, by = "FrequencyIndex") %>%
  dplyr::left_join(tt, by = "TimeIndex") %>%
  dplyr::select(Time, Frequency, Amplitude)

# head(sp)
#  Time Frequency Amplitude
#1    0   0.00000 -57.72730
#2    0  21.53320 -63.55554
#3    0  43.06641 -85.05077
#4    0  64.59961 -91.29989
#5    0  86.13281 -83.86144
#6    0 107.66602 -81.54240
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I understand the output. The object produced by spectro() contains time and amp vectors of the same length, presumably the amplitude value at any given time. But the freq vector is much shorter and linearly increases. Why does frequency not correspond with time? Is there a way to get pitch at a given time? Thanks again!

Comment: In this example, there are 71 times and 256 frequencies. These should be interpreted as the centres of time and frequency intervals (although I would have to look at the code to confirm this centre assumption). The first entry of `sp` is saying that at a time window centred on 0 and a frequency window centred on 0, the amplitude is -57.72730. The 257th row of `sp` will give the amplitude for the same frequency interval at the next time (which is 0.04726401).

Comment: I see. So if I understand correctly, it doesn't seem possible to extract what I want from this, which is essentially pitch plotted against time for a wav file.

Comment: It depends what you mean by pitch. If you mean the dominant frequency at a given time, then simply finding the frequency with the maximum amplitude might be what you want. There is a function in `seewave` called `dfreq` that does this.

Comment: Not sure if it's what I ultimately need, but that is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks again.